# How to migrate a JSON table that contains an array to SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mariadb

I'm a trainee front-end developer. Never really liked back-end so I know very little about SQL.

But here we are, in one of those adventuring times that I need to do the backend because I was assigned too. Well, we have an internal system for tracking some data about ourselves that we are rebuilding. The previous system used a JSON File to store its data, in a format like this:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "userId": 522,
  "effortDate": "2020-06-05",
  "data": [
    {
      "projectId": 14,
      "value": 7
    },
    {
      "projectId": 23,
      "value": 3
    }
  ],
  "updatedAt": "2020-06-08T10:13:11-03:00",
  "createdAt": "2020-06-08T10:13:11-03:00"
}
```

We are moving to SQL based database. So, with my basic understanding of how relational databases works,

I've built this model:

[image: I've built this model].

The problem is: at least for now, we are using the same front-end for the application, so I need the data parsed in the same format as it was back then when it was only a JSON. And for the basic operation of the system, it needs to require **all** the data from the now, two tables, all the time.

My first idea, was to kind mix them up, you know, by force, with two different SELECT's. Which I guess, isn't that bad <s>(maybe because it works)</s>, except we're dealing with thousands of entries, so I'm scared things might get slow. Here's the code I used to parse it up:

```
public function getAllEfforts() {
  /* Get all data from `effort` */
  $effortQuery = "SELECT id, userId, effortDate, createdAt, updatedAt
                  FROM efforts;";

  $efforts = $this->pdo
    ->query($effortQuery)
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  /* Get all data from `effort_data` */
  $effortDataQuery = "SELECT id, effortId, projectId, value
                      FROM efforts_data;";

  $effortsData = $this->pdo
    ->query($effortDataQuery)
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  /* Since, `effort` doesn't have a data field, let's define the array wished here */
  foreach($efforts as &$effortsUnity) {
    $effortsUnity['data'] = [];
  }

  /* Push the stuff from `effort_data` to the just created data array */
  foreach($effortsData as &$effortDataUnity) {
    $effortIndex = ($effortDataUnity['effortId'] - 1);

    unset($effortDataUnity['id']);
    unset($effortDataUnity['effortId']);

    array_push(
      $efforts[$effortIndex]['data'],
      $effortDataUnity
    );
  }
  
  return $efforts;
}
```

**My question is: is there any way to do it using only SQL?** Or any other optimal way of doing this besides using MongoDB or other JSON based DB which is not possible at the moment.

Sorry If I was not clear enough, it is my first question here, I'm willing to clarify any questions.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage MySQL's JSON functions to generate a nested JSON structure directly from the database.

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    userId, 
    effortDate, 
    createdAt, 
    updatedAt,
    (
        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT('projectId', ed.projectId, 'value', ed.value)
        )
        FROM efforts_data ed
        WHERE ed.effortId = e.id
    ) AS data
FROM efforts
```

This gives you one row per `efforts`, with a column called `data` that contains a JSON payload made of an array of objects coming table `efforts_data`.

You can go one step forward and stuff each row in a single object, if that's what you want:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
    'id', id, 
    'userId', userId, 
    'effortDate', effortDate, 
    'createdAt', createdAt, 
    'updatedAt', updatedAt,
    'data', (
        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT('projectId', ed.projectId, 'value', ed.value)
        )
        FROM efforts_data ed
        WHERE ed.effortId = e.id
    )
) res
FROM efforts
```

In MySQL < 5.7.22 or MariaDB < 10.5.0, where `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` is not yet available, one workaround is `GROUP_CONCAT()` and string concatenation. Basically you would rewite this:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT('projectId', ed.projectId, 'value', ed.value)
)
FROM efforts_data ed
WHERE ed.effortId = e.id
```

As:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    '[', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('projectId', ed.projectId, 'value', ed.value)),
    ']'
)
FROM efforts_data ed
WHERE ed.effortId = e.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd didn't even know MySQL had built-in JSON features. I'm looking out for those.

I'm getting an PDO Exception, though, ("#1305 - FUNCTION sistema_do_peru.JSON_ARRAYAGG does not exist"). Maybe it could just be my MySQL version, I'll try to fix it myself. Thanks for showing me the way!

Comment: @GabrielAndrade: which version of MySQL are you running? `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` was introduced in 5.7.22. `select version()` can tell you your current version.

Comment: Hello, I'm using the latest XAMMP release for development, so it is '10.4.13-MariaDB'.

Comment: JSON_ARRAYAGG was added in MariaDB 10.5.0. [see documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_arrayagg/)

Comment: @GabrielAndrade BTW you can install MySQL _per se_ separately and run it instead of MariaDB from XAMPP, it's how I'm working now, as MariaDB had other pitfalls.

Comment: @GabrielAndrade: I added a workaround for your MariaDB version.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: is there any way to do it using only SQL?

Yes, that's why you have the relationship between `efforts id` and `efforts_data effortId`:

```
SELECT e.id, e.userId, e.effortDate, e.createdAt, e.updatedAt,
       ed.id, ed.effortId, ed.projectId, ed.value
FROM efforts AS e, efforts_data AS ed
WHERE e.id = ed.effortId
```

Comment: comma seperated tables are long time out of use,because this is basically a crossjoin, where filter after joining, make a prper join

Comment: I'm not a fan of what I call "WHERE-clause joins" either.